# Handling asynchronous callbacks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I have the following function:

```
    function IsFacebookOpen() {
    var url;
    var facebookFound = false;
    chrome.windows.getAll({"populate":true}, function(getInfo) {
        for(var j = 0; typeof getInfo[j] != "undefined"; j++) {
            for(var i = 0; typeof getInfo[j].tabs[i] != "undefined"; i++) {
                url = getInfo[j].tabs[i].url;
                if(url.substr(url.indexOf("facebook", 0), url.indexOf(".com", 0)-url.indexOf("facebook", 0)) == "facebook") {
                    facebookFound = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return facebookFound;
}
```

That checks if one of the tabs in Google Chrome is facebook. The problem is that chromewindows.getAll is async, so the functions returns before all the tabs can be checked. This means that the return value is always FALSE since no tab is checked before it returns. If I force the function to wait by doing the following:

```
function IsFacebookOpen() {
    var url;
    var facebookFound = false;
    var done = false;
    chrome.windows.getAll({"populate":true}, function(getInfo) {
        for(var j = 0; typeof getInfo[j] != "undefined"; j++) {
            for(var i = 0; typeof getInfo[j].tabs[i] != "undefined"; i++) {
                url = getInfo[j].tabs[i].url;
                if(url.substr(url.indexOf("facebook", 0), url.indexOf(".com", 0)-url.indexOf("facebook", 0)) == "facebook") {
                    facebookFound = true;
                    done = true;
                }
            }
        }
        done = true;
    });
    while(!done) { };
    return facebookFound;
}
```

the function never returns, but if I use a alert() and halts the function for a split second, I get the correct return value.
How can I make return the correct value without using this alert()?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using callback function like

```
fbOpenResponse(isOpened){
    // do stuff
}
```

That you call when you have found (or not) the fb window...

It can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong.

```
function IsFacebookOpen(callback) {
    var url;
    chrome.windows.getAll({"populate":true}, function(getInfo) {
            for(var j = 0; typeof getInfo[j] != "undefined"; j++) {
            for(var i = 0; typeof getInfo[j].tabs[i] != "undefined"; i++) {
                url = getInfo[j].tabs[i].url;
                if(url.substr(url.indexOf("facebook", 0), url.indexOf(".com", 0)-url.indexOf("facebook", 0)) == "facebook") {
                    callback(true);
                }
            }
        }
        callback(false);
    });
}

// calling:
IsFacebookOpen(function (facebookOpen) {
    // insert code here
});
```

In a similar fashion to:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    // You put the code in here...
}, timeout);
// ... not in here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Javascript may be assynchronous but it *is not parellel*. The busy loop will run for ever and will never stop to give a chance for getAll to run after it gets done.

What you need to do is suck up to the fact that assynchronicity is "contagious" and turn IsFacebookOpen into an assynchronous function as well, as per Hello71's answer.